# How does colouring in python affect spacing in characters?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am writing some code for a sudoku game that I have to build for my university project in python. One of the criteria for the project is to display the letter entered by the user in a colour (for example, purple).

Essentially, the user enters something like 1 2 A in the terminal when prompted. 1 and 2 are the x and y coordinates of the board and A is the value the user is attempting to enter. Now, there are a bunch of constraints to what input is acceptable. To the best of my knowledge this code does not have much to do with the bug that I am facing. When I try to enter something in the board, it just moves the entire line back or front one space and it ruins the structure of my board.

For context, the board before any inputs looks something like this -

```
   1 2 3 4
  +-+-+-+-+
1 |   |  B|
2 |  B|   |
  +-+-+-+-+
3 |  C|  D|
4 |  A|B  |
  +-+-+-+-+
```

After input, the output *should* look like so when the enters something like 3 1 B-

```
   1 2 3 4
  +-+-+-+-+
1 |   |  B|
2 |  B|   |
  +-+-+-+-+
3 |B C|  D|
4 |  A|B  |
  +-+-+-+-+
```

Here's what actually happens -

```
   1 2 3 4
  +-+-+-+-+
1 |   |  B|
2 |  B|   |
  +-+-+-+-+
3 |BC|  D|
4 |  A|B  |
  +-+-+-+-+

// B appears in purple
```

I've been at this for days and still haven't figured out why I am facing this problem. The worst part is that the code works fine when I do not attempt to colour the letter entered by the user. I asked my proff about this but she said I have a bug in my code. I am stuck :(

My code -

to display the sudoku board -

```py
board = eval(input("Enter your 2-d board (4x4): "))
game_on = True

'''
example board - 
[[' ', ' ', ' ', 'B' ], [' ', 'B', ' ', ' ' ], [' ','C',' ','D' ], [' ', 'A', 'B', ' ']]
'''

def display_board(): 

    print('  {:2}{:2}{:2}{:2}'.format(
        1, 2, 3, 4
    ))

    print('  {:2}{:2}{:2}{:3}'.format(
        '+-', '+-', '+-', '+-+'
    ))

    print('{} {}{:2}{:}{}{:2}{}{}'.format(
        1, '|', board[0][0], board[0][1],
        '|', board[0][2], board[0][3], '|'
    ))

    print('{} {}{:2}{:}{}{:2}{}{}'.format(
        2, '|', board[1][0], board[1][1],
        '|', board[1][2], board[1][3], '|'
    ))

    print('  {:2}{:2}{:2}{:3}'.format(
        '+-', '+-', '+-', '+-+'
    ))

    print('{} {}{:2}{:}{}{:2}{}{}'.format(
        3, '|', board[2][0], board[2][1],
        '|', board[2][2], board[2][3], '|'
    ))

    print('{} {}{:2}{:}{}{:2}{}{}'.format(
        4, '|', board[3][0], board[3][1],
        '|', board[3][2], board[3][3], '|'
    ))

    print('  {:2}{:2}{:2}{:3}'.format(
        '+-', '+-', '+-', '+-+'
    ))

display_board()
```

to add new letter (entered by the user) to the board -

```py
while game_on:
    try:

      attempt = input("Type a row number, a column number, and a letter (e.g., 1 2 A): ")
      attempt_cleaned = tuple(fstrip(attempt)) # fstrip() is a function I made to remove all whitespaces in a function. tuple(fstrip(attempt)) = ("1", "2", "A")
      x = int(attempt_cleaned[0]) - 1
      y = int(attempt_cleaned[1]) - 1
      val = attempt_cleaned[2]

      PURPLE = "\033[0;35m"
      NORMAL = "\033[0m"

      board[x][y] = PURPLE + val + NORMAL # coloring letter entered by the user 
      display_board()

    except:
        print("Invalid input.")
        display_board()

    finally:

      if all_cells_filled(): # function to check if the game is completed. I have not included its code because I believe it's irrelevant to the bug I am facing. 
        print("Good game!")
        game_on = False
```

I know this is a very long question but I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.